# jQuery - hight of DIV not calculatet fast enough after synchrounous ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'externalData.html',
    success: function( result ) {

        $("#divToFill").html(result);

        targetDiv = "#target1" ;
        $('body').attr('target_height', $(targetDiv).height());  // PROBLEM !

    },
    async: false
});
```

externalData.html

```
<div id="target1">
    <a href="">
        <span class="imageBox">
            <img  class="displayimage" src="img/dummy.jpg">
        </span>
        <strong class="productname">product</strong><em class="productinfo">info</em> 
        <span class="priceBox">
            <span class="price">9,95 €</span>
        </span> 
    </a>
</div>
```

The Problem is, that the height of the targetDiv is calculatet before the Image is loaded. Sometimes I get a height of 50px instead of 180px.

'.html()' should be synchrounous and  'async: false' should also force to fire the success event after the data is loaded. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The loading of the image has nothing to do with the ajax-call, you page just needs time to load the image, same as when the page loads (when you would use `window.onload` to be sure everything is loaded).

You can use `document.getElementById(imageID).complete`, I've had very reliable results with that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'externalData.html',
    success: function( result ) {
        $("#divToFill").html(result);

        targetDiv = "#target1";
        imageID = "imageID"; //so you need to give your image an ID
        getHeight(targetDiv,imageID);
    },
    async: false
});

function getHeight(targetDiv, imageID) {
    if (document.getElementById(imageID).complete) { //this checks whether the image has finished loading
        $('body').attr('target_height', $(targetDiv).height());
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){getHeight(targetDiv,imageID);},5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only proper solution would be to wait until the image finishes loading (unless you know the image dimensions in advance, in that case, just specify it manually in the CSS) and then do whatever you want.

This can be a little tricky because there are numerous browser caveats that make it difficult to detect when an image loaded. Luckily, you can use [this](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) - make sure to create the event listener right after your .html and put the rest of your callback inside inside the imagesloaded callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You need o wait till image loading...for that you can place the condition of image loading and then get the height of target div.